# How to format a xml when opening in a new tab?

Tags: asp.net

With the code below I'm output a xml text in a different tab, but when I click it on it doesnt format in xml.
The column in the database table its [xml] [xml] NULL,not sure if that matters in this case.

How do format the data to correct XML when clicking on the link?

```
  @if (Model != null && Model.Any())
                    {

                        var count = 1;
                        foreach (var r in Model)
                        {

                                    <a href="#" class="btn-file" data-id="@count" id="filelink@(count)">Open XML</a>

                                    @Html.Hidden("file" + count, r.xml)

                            }
<script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).on("click", ".btn-file", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var btn = $(this);
                var id = btn.data("id");

                var xml = $("#file" + id).val();

                var myWindow = window.open("@Url.Action("SearchData")/test.xml");
              //  myWindow.document.write('<?xml version="1.0" ?>' + xml);
myWindow.document.write('<pre>' + xml + '</pre?');
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Wrap the xml in the <pre> tag.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov i try that and it does make it look better